# ASP.NET Core 3.1 Web API and Entity Framework Core : AutoMapper getting error mapping types MIssing Type mpa configuration or unsupported mapping

Tags: c#, automapper

I am using Automapper to copy the content from DTO view model to an entity class but I get an error:

> Error mapping types:
> ViewModelDto -> Models.MyEntity
> Type Map configuration:
> ViewModelDto -> ViewModelDto -> Models.MyEntity
> EmbeddedClass

The last section of the string is an embedded object which is the issue that is throwing the exception. It is defined in source and destination class as a collection of records.

In my incoming ViewModelDto, the embedded class is listed as

```
public class ViewModelDto
{
  public List<MyEntity> MyEntities {get;set;}
}
```

In the `MyEntity` class, this is autogenerated by scaffolding

```
public partial class MyEntity
{
    public MyEntity()
    {
        MyEntities = new HashSet<MyEntity>();
    }

    public virtual ICollection<MyEntity> MyEntities {get;set;}
}
```

In my `MappingProfile.cs`:

```
public MappingProfile()
{
    CreateMap<List<ViewModelDto>, List<MyEntity>>().ReverseMap();
}
```

When looking at both ViewModelDto and MyEntity class, the MyEntity is defined in both files. Not sure what is causing the thrown exception

Tried a few new things, in the mappingprofile.s

```
CreateMap<ViewModelDto, Drill>)().ForMember(dest => dest.MyEntity, opt => opt.UseDestination());
CreateMapCreateMap<List<ViewModelDto>, List<MyEntity>>)();
```

In my startup.cs

```
In the ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
  services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(Startup));
}
```

Comment: Your configuration is right. I tried it and it worked. The problem might be on startup configuration for the Automapper to find the profiles. can u show us the startup class or the configuration where you added the Automapper injection?

Comment: make sure the Automapper injection finds the namespace for your profle MappingProfile.cs

Comment: Added the services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(Startup)); inside the startup.cs. See above.

Comment: https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Lists-and-arrays.html

Answer (score 0):

Seems like there is a Mapping Issue between the List and HashSet, you can try this :

```
CreateMap<ViewModelDto, MyEntity>(MemberList.Source)
    .ForMember(dest => dest.MyEntities, opt => opt.UseDestinationValue());
```

With this, AutoMapper will try to use the destination value type (HashSet) instead of the origin (List).

Comment: Tried that but still get exception

Comment: How about converting your HashSet<T> to a List<T> any reason you're using a HashSet ?

Comment: that was autogenerated by entity scaffolding

Comment: One more question, so your MyEntity class has a collection of same type MyEntity ?

Comment: Try to make it List<MyEntity> just to see if this solves the exception.

Comment: Yes, List<MyEntity> MyEntities is a collection of MyEntity records, not sure where is not defined or

Comment: Nope, still throwing the same error. Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping

Comment: Instead of CreateMap<List<ViewModelDto>, List<MyEntity>>().ReverseMap() you should do CreateMap<ViewModelDto, MyEntity>().ReverseMap()

Comment: Got both of them in my mappingProfile.cs, still getting error

Answer (score 0):

Added this to my Startup.cs to resolve the issue, Need to register the MappingProfile in the Automapper Service

services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(MappingProfile));

Comment: Orginally I had services.AddAutomapper(typeof(Startup));